# Unable to launch Skyrim: The Elder Scrolls with PlayOnLinux

Tags: wine, playonlinux

Hello fellow from stack exchange!

I've been trying to run Skyrim on ubuntu using playonlinux with no success.

After several installation error's, i've found myself stuck in this error message:

```
wine: Call from 0x7f295cd001da to unimplemented function VCRUNTIME140.dll.__C_specific_handler, aborting
err:seh:setup_exception stack overflow 4416 bytes in thread 0022 eip 00007f295cd384dd esp 00000000001404c0 stack 0x140000-0x141000-0x240000
```

Any hints on solving it? Thank's for your attention!

Note: Im using Codex .iso Skyrim, 64bit version.

Comment: Do you have VCRUNTIME140.dll? Google for it (ie. "vcruntime140.dll download" and copy the dll file into your skyrim folder or install the runtime libraries via winetricks ... `sudo apt install winetricks` then `winetricks vcrun2015`

Comment: "Unknown arg vcrun2015"

Comment: Try `winetricks dlls`. It'll pop up a window in which you should see a list of libraries you can install. You should be able to scroll down the list until you see vcrun2015. Select it and install it. If you are still having problems it might be a known bug in winetricks. See this gitpage for instructions on how to fix the issue [https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/issues/575](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/issues/575)

Comment: Ok, i've tried to apply this solution, but im getting an error while trying to install vcrun2015, "Working around wine bug 37781"

Comment: Note: command wine vc_redist.x86.exe returned status 109.  Aborting.